# Error in spring when using scoped-proxy beans

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am getting an error in spring when trying to use session scoped beans, the error is:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.usuarioAutenticado': Scope 'session' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
```

My configuration is:
web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            WEB-INF/applicationContext*.xml
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/sys/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

And the bean:

```
<bean id="usuarioAutenticado" class="com.wi.security.UsuarioAutenticado" scope="session">
    <aop:scoped-proxy/>
</bean>
```

I have been searching about this issue and all I have found is to add the following lines to web.xml:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

This solves the issue, but the side effect is that all my @Scheduled annotated methods are running twice, I think that is because spring is creating two contexts.

Reading Spring docs it says:

> DispatcherServlet, RequestContextListener and RequestContextFilter all do exactly
>   the same thing, namely bind the HTTP request object to the Thread that is servicing that request. This
>   makes beans that are request- and session-scoped available further down the call chain.

So, I don't understand why is not working with just the DispatcherServlet configuration.
Hope someone can help me to find a solution, I am new to spring.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

I was setting in my web.xml the contextConfigLocation:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/applicationContext*.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

and then setting it again in servlet configuration:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/applicationContext*.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

the solution was to remove the servlet param-value:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value/>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```